# I don't even know where to begin... [Installing Node]

Tags: steam

I saw this video here 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO38PzVjvro

And I wanted to follow it to create my own HourBoost bot. So I purchased a £3 Ubuntu VPS from OVH and tried to follow his video directly and it doesn't work. I am beyond confused as he is using the full OS and mine is just the terminal. I am extremely new to this so I don't even know where I have gone wrong.

So far I'm here

[image: Picture of my directory]

Could anyone take the time to help me?

I don't think its that complicated considering the video is only 5 minutes.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. How is your question related to [steam](/tags/steam/info)? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

Installing node is well documented on the NodeJS site.

Basic installation for version 7.x (that you're attempting):

1. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -`
2. `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

If you need to compile your own addons, you will also need to run:

- `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`

I hope that helps!

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: It  says it can't find the package to install even after running the first part. And now I think I have fucked up my whole VPS. And since its a new VPS I can't reset it. I have no clue on how to install any of this and I feel like ive wasted £3

Comment: Can you please post a copy of the errors you're getting?

Comment: If I add you on skype could I give you the login details of the VPS and could you help me?

Comment: It finally worked for some reason.

Comment: That's good news. Have there been any further errors related to the installation of NodeJS?

Comment: Nope I'm stuck with a failed to start error tho :L I have completely done everything and now I'm stuck :(

Comment: OK. If you found my answer helpful, don't forget to mark it. If you have further issues that aren't related to NodeJS, you can easily start a new question. Remember to include any errors or screenshots that might help troubleshoot the issue :)